# How to keep shower caulk clean

Tags: shower, mold, caulk

We have a tile surround shower that has a fascia covering that is attached between the bottom edge of the tile and the bathtub using tub/shower/tile caulk.

The caulk is marked for use in wet locations,  so i expected it would resist mold and mildew growth.   But as you can see from the picture it is nasty.

I would like to to this fascia and caulk off one last time (3rd time around by now,  over the course of 10 years) and replace it with something that won't be so tough to maintain.

What should i use instead?[image: gunky tub]

Answer (score 1):

I have used three things in the past:

1. Toilet cleaning bleach gel every other month or so.
2. Spray bleach cleaner occasionally.
3. Bleach/baking soda paste, with diluted bleach spray every few hours to keep moist.  Paint on with a cheap paintbrush as the bleach will destroy the bristles.

Once you have given up hope, use the third option and cover the paste with saran wrap to keep it from drying out.  Overnight should save it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with mold growth in shower stalls is unless you kill all the mold it will eventually return. Scrubbing the surface with bleach will get the expected results of no mold. The problem is that mold spores can grow behind the caulking and infiltrate through it. The best strategy is to cut the caulking out with a utility knife making cuts on top and bottom of the bead. Work a piece out that you can grasp and pull the length out. Remove as much caulking as possible. Now apply the bleach/water solution from a spray bottle allowing it to sit for several minutes. Scrub with a bristled brush and repeat. Use a dry rag to dry the joint. I've found that waving a heat gun (or hair dryer) on low above the joint completely dries (and kills spores) the joint. Careful with the heat! Once dry refill with a non-latex caulk. Silicone is the most resistant to mold followed by urethane.